# issue with installing rails using rubygem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, gem

I tried doing the following:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

and I always get the error message:

```
Successfully installed rails-3.0.9
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.9...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.9...
file 'lib' not found
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938641/file-lib-not-found-when-installing-rails-3-1-on-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: now I am getting ERROR: Error running 'GEM_HOME='/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8' GEM_PATH='/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'  gem install rails    ', please read /home/herlamba/.rvm/log/gem.install.log

Comment: looking at the log it says:  You don't have write permissions into the /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684810/rubygems-installation-errors-both-when-using-sudo-and-not-using-sudo

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with documentation, the gem itself was installed properly, to avoid reporting error use:

```
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```